# C++ How does a vector of pointers affect performance?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, vector, stl

I am wondering how a std::vector of pointers to objects affects the performance of a program, vs. using a std::vector directly containing the objects. Specifically I am referring to the speed of the program.

I was taught to use the std::vector over other STL such as the std::list for it's speed, due to all of it's data being stored contiguously in memory, rather than being fragmented. This meant that iterating over the elements was fast, however my thinking is that if my vector contains pointers to the objects, then the objects can still be stored anywhere in memory and only the pointers are stored contiguously. I am wondering how this would affect the performance of a program when it comes to iterating over the vector and accessing the objects.

My current project design uses a vector of pointers so that I can take advantage of virtual functions however i'm unsure whether this is worth the speed hit i may encounter when my vector becomes very large. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the objects are polymorphic, you have to use pointers. If you make it a vector of objects, you'll slice them when you store them into the vector. And if you need to maintain object identity, you lose that with a vector of objects, because it makes copies.

Comment: The pointers are stored contiguously. The data referenced by the pointer is Crom-knows-where. Only way to know for sure if this is a performance problem is profiling both options. But before you head off and do that, does the current version meet the required performance spec? Is there any need for improvement at all?

Comment: @Barmar yes the objects are polymorphic, but my reason for asking the question was more to do with whether I will need to redesign my project due to these performance implications. Could you explain what you mean when you say "you'll slice them when you store them into the vector"? I'm not sure I understand you fully.

Comment: ***more to do with whether I will need to redesign my project due to these performance implications*** Most likely not.

Comment: @user4581301 My project is a particle system, and current design runs fine with a small number of particles (5000 -ish), however I wish for it to run just as well with a larger number (20000 -ish), currently it is unacceptably slow at that number and I am wondering if this could be the design flaw.

Comment: I doubt that this is the cause of your slowdown.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your opinion, I'll look at the other parts of my design instead.

Comment: Run your program through a profiler to see what piece of code its taking up your time, then hunt and kill the inefficiencies in that piece of code. If that turns out to be how you store your data, so be it, but nothing beats hard numbers when making a decision. Hacking at the code because you have a feeling... Works for Jedi, I guess. Meesa no Jedi, okeeday? Take a look at using valgrind or whatever's built into Visual Studio. If it's all you have available, gprof is better than nothing.

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Ensuring contiguous data was important in the days when memory was very limited, so paging was a serious performance drain. This is less of an issue these days, when RAM is measured in gigabytes. Cache misses can sometimes be an issue, but it's not nearly as big a performance hit as paging was.

Comment: Actually in C++ on a modern CPU cache coherence, and branch predicatbility is by far the #1 performace concern for hot code. Roughly every layer of cache you need to travel to for data, add another 0 onto the number of cycles it'll take. L1 ~10, L2 ~100, RAM ~1000

Comment: Hot code... That'll be about 425F, I guess. How long do I bake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the polymorphism, as people have said, you should store the pointers to the base. If, later, you decide this code is hot and needs to optimise it's cpu cache usage you can do that say by making the objects fit cleanly in cache lanes and/or with a custom allocator to ensure code locality of the dereferenced data.

Slicing is when you store objects by value Base and copy construct or allocate into them a Derived, Derived will be Sliced, the copy constructor or allocator only takes a Base and will ignore any data in Derived, there isn't enough space allocated in Base to take the full size of Derived. i.e. if Base is 8 bytes and Derived is 16, there's only enough room for Base's 8 bytes in the destination value even if you provided a copy constructor/allocator that explicitly took a Dervived.

I should say it's really not worth thinking about data cache coherence if you're using virtualisation heavily that wont be elided by the optimiser. An instruction cache miss is far more devestating than a data cache miss and virtualisation can cause instruction cache misses because it has to look up the vtable pointer before loading the function into the instruction cache and so can't preemptively load them.

CPU's tend to like to preload as much data as they can into caches, if you load an address an entire cache lane (~64 bytes) will be loaded into a cache lane and often it will also load the cache lane before and after which is why people are so keen on data locality.

So in your vector of pointers scenario when you load the first pointer you'll get lots of pointers in the cache at once loading through the pointer will trigger a cache miss and load up the data around that object, if your actual particles are 16 bytes and local to each other, you wont lose much beyond this. if they're all over the heap and massive you will get very cache churny on each iteration and relatively ok while working on a particle.

Traditionally, particle systems tend to be very hot and like to pack data tightly, it's common to see 16 byte Plain Old Data particle systems which you iterate linearly over with very predicatble branching. meaning you can generally rely on 4 particles per cache lane and have the prefetcher stay well ahead of your code.

I also should say that cpu caches are cpu dependant and i'm focusing on intel x86. Arm for example tends to be quite a bit behind intel & the pipeline is less complex, the prefetcher less capable and so cache misses can be less devastating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very insightful, I was not aware of the specifics of cache misses and your example helped me to understand them. Extra thanks for explaining slicing!